# Manipulating a struct which is a class property in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, class, object, struct

I've been trying to work with MATLAB classes & structs in order to develop a traffic simulation. I have not worked actively with MATLAB classes before, so it gets a bit tricky at times. This questions involves manipulating a struct, which is a property of a class.

Top-level access

```
vehicles_handle = VehiclesHandle;
vehicles_handle.CreateVehicles(InitialTrafficDensity);
vehicles_handle.vehicles(1)
```

Class definition

```
classdef VehiclesHandle
    %VEHICLESHANDLE Summary of this class goes here
    %   Detailed explanation goes here

    properties 
        active_vehicles_count
        vehicles
    end

    methods (Access = public)
        function obj = VehiclesHandle
            obj.active_vehicles_count = 0;
            obj.vehicles = struct('lane',0,'position',0,'velocity',0); 
        end
        function obj = CreateVehicles(obj,InitialTrafficDensity)
            obj.active_vehicles_count = obj.active_vehicles_count + 1;
            obj.vehicles(1).lane = 1;
            obj.vehicles(1).position = 3;
            obj.vehicles(1).velocity = 3;
            obj.vehicles(2).lane = 2;
            obj.vehicles(2).position = 3;
            obj.vehicles(2).velocity = 3;
        end
```

Now, I can't see the output as expected (which is vehicles_handle.vehicles(1)), I see them the properties of the vehicle 1 as 0's. The situation changes, of course, when I put then in the function VehiclesHandle, but I want to handle creation of vehicles this way.

I know that the code might not be the most efficient way to handle this, but I really do want to learn about handling a struct in this class without pain. Thanks for all the constructive comments and help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting rid of the problem is quite easy:

```
classdef VehiclesHandle
```

has to be

```
classdef VehiclesHandle < handle
```

And to understand why, please read [Comparison of Handle and Value Classes](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/comparing-handle-and-value-classes.html).

Comment: Thank you very much